# Extending understanding of Applicative from liftA2 to liftA3

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, purely-functional

I am trying to get a hold over understanding Applicative functors currently. And my understanding is falling short somewhere but I cannot pinpoint where.
Source from where I am trying to build an understanding [CIS 194 UPenn](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis1940/spring13/lectures.html) - [Homework 10](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis1940/spring13/hw/10-applicative.pdf)

I am working with a custom data type and its Applicative instance which are as follows :

```
-- A parser for a value of type a is a function which takes a String
-- represnting the input to be parsed, and succeeds or fails; if it
-- succeeds, it returns the parsed value along with the remainder of
-- the input.
newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }

instance Functor Parser where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
  fmap fn parserA = Parser (fmap (first fn) . parseAFunc)
    where parseAFunc = runParser parserA

appliedFunc p1 p2 str = case runParser p1 str of
    Nothing        -> Nothing
    Just (f, str2) -> case runParser p2 str2 of
        Nothing        -> Nothing
        Just (x, str3) -> Just (f x, str3)

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure a = Parser (\s -> Just (a, s))
  p1 <*> p2 = Parser (appliedFunc p1 p2)  

-- For example, 'satisfy' takes a predicate on Char, and constructs a
-- parser which succeeds only if it sees a Char that satisfies the
-- predicate (which it then returns).  If it encounters a Char that
-- does not satisfy the predicate (or an empty input), it fails.
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy p = Parser f
  where
    f [] = Nothing    -- fail on the empty input
    f (x:xs)          -- check if x satisfies the predicate
                        -- if so, return x along with the remainder
                        -- of the input (that is, xs)
        | p x       = Just (x, xs)
        | otherwise = Nothing  -- otherwise, fail

-- Using satisfy, we can define the parser 'char c' which expects to
-- see exactly the character c, and fails otherwise.
char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = satisfy (== c)

-- Below is a parser for positive Ints which parses
-- the prefix of contiguous digits in a given String
-- as an Int 
posUse :: Parser Int
posUse = Parser f
  where
    f xs
      | null ns   = Nothing
      | otherwise = Just (read ns, rest)
      where (ns, rest) = span isDigit xs

-- Below function takes a function and a pair and returns a pair 
-- with the function applied to the first element of pair
first :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
first fn (x, y) = (fn x, y)
```

Using all the above setup, I am trying to construct some more complicated Parsers using simple Parsers defined above. So fmap has type `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. And as per my understanding currently, Applicative allows us to extend `fmap` to functions that take n-ary functions and n Functor parameters and return the resultant functor.

`fmap` can be defined in terms of `pure` and `<*>` as :

```
fmap1 :: Applicative f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap1 f x = pure f <*> x
```

I understand why the above will work given that the implementations of `pure` and `<*>` are appropriate since the types nicely line up.

Extending this to `fmap2` aka `liftA2` :

```
fmap2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
fmap2 f x y = pure f <*> x <*> y
```

My understanding of why the above works is as follows :
`pure g` will have type `f (a -> b -> c)` And so therefore `pure g <*> x` will have type `f (b -> c)` since functions are curried. Then this type combined with the type type of y (`f b`) using `<*>` will finally give us the type of the result which is `f c` which is what we needed the type `fmap2` to be.

This understanding did not break down when I tried to construct a Parser out of 2 simple Parsers as follows :

```
-- This Parser expects to see the characters ’a’ and ’b’ and returns them
-- as a pair.
abParser = liftA2 (\c1 c2 -> (c2 c1)) (char 'a') (char 'b')
```

The above works as expected.

But when I try to make the parser `intPair` which reads two integer values separated by a space and returns the integer values in a list using `liftA3` my understanding of lift is not working since I expect the following to work but the linter complains :

```
intPair :: Parser [Int]
intPair = liftA3 (\x y z -> [z x]) posUse (char ' ') posUse
```

The above does not compile as the last argument needs to have the type `Parser (Int -> a)`  (according to type inference) but I have passed `posUse` which has the type `Parser Int`.

TL;DR :
Sorry for the long description. If anyone does not want to go through it all (expecially the custom data type and its Applicative and Functor instance) -- please let me know if my understanding of why `fmap2` aka `liftA2` works is correct and how does that understanding extend to `liftA3` ?
The definition of `liftA3` seems to be something different than just an extension of the definition of `liftA2` using `<*>` and `pure`.

Edit 1 :
As stated above, the below line was being complained about by the linter

```
intPair :: Parser [Int]
intPair = liftA3 (\x y z -> [z x]) posUse (char ' ') posUse
```

The linter expected the type for the last argument to be `Parser (Int -> a)`.
But after I defined an explicit function instead of passing a lambda, it worked as I expected to work.

```
fnn :: Int -> Char -> Int -> [Int]
fnn arg1 arg2 arg3 = [arg1, arg3]
intPair = liftA3 fnn posUse (char ' ') posUse
```

It works as I expected.

Comment: (1) type signature of `intPair` is actually type signature of `liftA3`. `intPair` itself should be just `Parser [Int]`. (2) did you skip a comma between `z` and `x` in the square brackets?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Sorry I wrote the wrong type for `intPair`.. Yes its supposed to be `Parser [Int]`

Comment: The equivalent to the `fnn` you give in the edit is `\x y z -> [z, x]` with a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just made a silly mistake when converting from a named function to an anonymous one. Contrast:

```
fnn arg1 arg2 arg3 = [arg1, arg3] -- your working code
fnn = \x y z -> [z x]             -- your broken code
fnn = \x y z -> [z, x]            -- type-correct code
fnn = \x y z -> [x, z]            -- more correct translation of your working code
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your understanding of `liftA2` is correct, and `liftA3` is just more of the same. I can't guess  why it looks different to you, but inlining the definition of `liftA2` into the definition of `liftA3` may help.

```
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) 
                        -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f x y = pure f <*> x <*> y

liftA3 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c -> d) 
                        -> f a -> f b -> f c -> f d
liftA3 f a b c = liftA2 f a b <*> c
```

I took these definitions from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html, and rearranged the definition of `liftA2` a little to make it more explicit - it matches your `fmap2` exactly.

Now, note that `liftA3` includes a call to `liftA2 f a b`. We know how `liftA2 f a b` is defined, and because of purity, we can always inline definitions to yield semantically identical terms. So let's do that:

```
liftA3 f a b c = (pure f <*> a <*> b) <*> c
```

The parentheses are redundant, but I put them in while substituting just in case. Now if we remove them, we see there is no new idea here:

```
liftA3 f a b c = pure f <*> a <*> b <*> c
```

We lift the function, yielding `f (a -> b -> c -> d)`, then apply that to `a` with `<*>` to get an `f (b -> c -> d)`, and so on, all the way to an `f d` at the end.